# Facebook integration isn't working properly

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I've integrated facebook sdk in my demo app for facebook integration. When i click on the button fragment appears and i'm able to login but it doesn't revert with any values. I'm not having anything on logcat.

This is my Code :

```
package com.example.manishnegi.facebooklogin;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LoginButton btn;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    btn=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    btn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AccessToken accessToken=loginResult.getAccessToken();
           GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+object.getString("name"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                System.out.println( object.getString("name"));
                                System.out.println( object.getString("gender"));

                            }
                            catch (JSONException ex)
                            {
                               System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "name,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Please help I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You also generate HASHKEY like this:

```
private void getHashKey() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("RAJAT",
                    "KeyHash: "
                            + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                                    Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }

}
```

`getHashKey()` mthod call in `onCreate()` and use this hash key on facebook developer console.

And check flowing entry done in AndroidManifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderandyourappidfromfacebookconsole"
        android:exported="true" />
```

i hope this work for you...

Comment: @Brucode  please check what you add App ID in provider tag in android manifest OR internet permission......

Comment: that is fine . but it is not showing anything and i'm not even able to launch login screen on emulator

Comment: idk the version but I recently downloaded it from developer console of fb . so i guess it's the latest one

Comment: becoz facebook developer console also present old sdk